# Proper noun with an indefinte article

Tags: indefinite-articles, proper-nouns

Merry Christmas and Happy New Year are proper nouns. But, why are they used with an indefinite article as in "I wish you a Happy New Year/Merry Christmas.

Comment: _Christmas_ and _New Year_ are not necessarily proper nouns, though they do share some properties with proper nouns, particularly _Christmas_. More to the point, though, there's nothing strange about proper nouns being used with articles (definite or indefinite), so I don't quite understand what you're asking. The indefinite article is there to carry out its main function: marking indefiniteness.

Answer (score 0):

Just because a noun or phrase is capitalized doesn't necessarily mean it is a proper noun or phrase. Proper nouns (usually) don't take an article because they are used to name specific one-of-a-kind items. However, Christmas and Happy New Year are not *proper nouns* because

1. Christmas is short for Christmas Day and the word *day* is a countable noun. It is not a proper noun.
2. New Year is short for New Year's Day or New Year's. It also uses the same countable noun *day*.
3. Both of them can be pluralized as in

   > How many *Christmases* did you spend abroad?
   >
   > There are two New Year's *Days* in some Asian countries. One is solar and the other is lunar.

You rarely say "A good morning!", "A good afternoon!" or "A good evening!" because the indefinite article is not required in greetings as they don't require a full sentence. That's why you don't need to use the indefinite article when saying "Merry Christmas!" and "Happy New Year!"